# how to get the value of a variable of dynamically compiled C# code

Tags: c#, variables, compiler-construction

I'm at constructing a piece of code at run-time and compiling it run-time. Now i need to get the result of a variable in dynamic code at run-time. Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "Example.exe", true);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @"using System.Linq;
            class Program {
              public static void Main(string[] args) {
                int abc=10;
                bool myresult=false;

                if(abc==10)
                  myresult=true;
                else
                   myresult=false;
              }
            }");
        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
    }
}
```

I want runtime code to return value of  **myresult** varaible in my main program and how do i get it.

Comment: After compiling your code you could simply execute the result file by using the `Process` class and catch the `ExitCode` from it.
Btw: You could then optimize your code: `Environment.Exit(abc == 10);`

Comment: I tried as per the example given in link.. but still it did not work http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation_2.aspx

Comment: @sia follow the example in `ShowExpressionResults` (in your link) which loads the compiled assembly, finds a class in it, finds a method in the class and runs the method and prints the method's output

Comment: will try once again and update results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1**) You can load the compiled assembly as piece of code and call any method with any argument passing contract directly. Following modified example prints [image]

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "Example.exe", true);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @"using System.Linq;
            class Program {
              public static void Main(string[] args) {}

              public static string Main1(int abc) {
                bool myresult=false;

                if(abc==10)
                  myresult=true;
                else
                  myresult=false;

                return abc.ToString() + "": "" + (myresult ? ""myresult is true"" : ""myresult is false"");
              }
            }");
        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));

        var scriptClass = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Program");
        var scriptMethod1 = scriptClass.GetMethod("Main1", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        Console.WriteLine(scriptMethod1.Invoke(null, new object[] { 10 }).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(scriptMethod1.Invoke(null, new object[] { 20 }).ToString());
    }
}
```

**(2)** Or you can run the compiled `Example.exe` with any command line arguments you want, parse them and return the results any way you want. Console applications usually communicate complex input or output results through files and overall success/failure indicate through [Process.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx). There are quite many available options, some of them outlined in Stack Overflow question [Returning a string from a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774155/returning-a-string-from-a-console-application)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new similar code to use "Example.exe" as a reference and use "Program" class to get the result. Also, you will need to manually trigger the main and should have a static vaariable to store the result. Also need to make hold the completion of that program before reading that variable.

If I am understanding it correct, you are compiling and runnign an Executable, which is yet to be created.
That means, you need to assume its successful creation and work with your code in a string and have one more executable created to run it.