# error return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Tags: c#

The return(match) is giving me a headache! When I change it into Console.WriteLine(match) it gives me the return I expect but when I try to use the return(match) it gives me an error. I just don't know what to change here so any suggestions would be appreciated!

regards, James

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadTextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    fileLines.Add(line);
                    string pattern = @"(\w+)@(\w+).([a-z]+)";
                    Match match = Regex.Match((line), pattern);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        return(match);                        
                    }


                }

            }
```

Comment: `Main` is a `void` function. Who are you returning to?

Comment: You can't `return` within a `void` method. What are you trying to do with the value?

Comment: it looks like you want to get out of your while loop at that time, simply use the `break;` statement

Comment: Are you trying to output the matched value? Set the exit code for the app?

Comment: You should read a book on C# if you have so little knowledge of the language to the point you don't even understand return statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a string from a console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774155/returning-a-string-from-a-console-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a `void` method (`void Main`). `void` methods do not have a return value, so just `return;` by itself is all that's allowed.

BTW, `return` is not a function in C#, it's a statement, so there is no need for parenthesis.

Comment: OK, the error is gone. When I use the return the value of "match" will be returned, is that correct?

Comment: @JamesW You can't return match in Main because Main's expected return value is void, meaning it expects to not get a returned value and will actually error when it has a return value.

Comment: ok, got that, no value, just return!. So what do I change (void?) to get the value for match returned? If I change it to "string" the next errors are: 

CS0161: 'Program.Main(string[])': not all code paths return a value

CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to 'string

The value of "match" should be used as an input string for a e-mailparser

Answer (score 2):

`Main` returns a `void` if you want to return something else change the signature. Note that typically the return value of `Main` is called an error code where non-zero is considered an error.

If you create another function and put your logic into it you could then use return.

On the other hand if all you are looking to do is leave the `while` you instead need to make `Match match;` be after `string line;` and use `break;` to get out instead of `return`.

Comment: thanks for the respond. I'm not sure I totally get what you are trying to say but I'll try later!